# Appcache offline

Tags: manifest, html5-appcache, manifest.cache

We are working on content loading where in case if we are connected,the content should be brought from network. If we go offline, it should bring from cache. what settings should we do perform this. kindly guide.

regards,
balaji

Answer (score 1):

Keep the following code in appcache.manifest file

```
NETWORK:
*
```

So that when in online it takes the files from server.